# Using listagg on as many will fit [Oracle]

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a query which hits the 2000 character limit when I try to aggregate it, and I’d like to take just as many elements as will fit.

So the data looks like this

| id | summary | priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | text | 1 |
| a | goes | 2 |
| a | here | 3 |
| b | unaffected | 1 |

and assuming I join the fields with “, “ and have a length limit of 10 characters, I want this to produce

| id | summaries |
| --- | --- |
| a | text, goes |
| b | unaffected |

rather than “text, goes, here”.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you on? If you're on 12c+ then you can use ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2

Comment: This is almost perfect. Is there a way to tune the number of characters it accepts?

Comment: I don't see that option, but if you wanted to trim it to be shorter than the overflow limit, you could trim after the fact like this:  substr(listagg(...), 1, 100)  . You could add a case statement to add an ellipsis if necessary. This would be in addition to the ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE, since you need that to avoid an error

Comment: @tylert I’ll accept if you paste that into an answer.

Comment: thank you but the other answers look even more complete now.

Answer (score 1):

You've already learnt about possibility of truncating overflow. Substring *will* return shorten result, but that might look *ugly* if words are "cut" in the middle. Here's a function which does that nicely, paying attention about end of the word and concatenating ellipsis (`...`) if string is actually longer than what you got.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2     FUNCTION f_trim_text (par_tekst IN VARCHAR2, par_len IN NUMBER)
  3        RETURN VARCHAR2
  4     IS
  5        l_str_1      VARCHAR2 (4000);     -- trim PAR_TEKST to PAR_LEN length
  6        l_space_pos  NUMBER; -- position of the 2nd space in  L_STR_1 from end of the string
  7        retval       VARCHAR2 (4000);
  8     BEGIN
  9        IF    par_tekst IS NULL
 10           OR par_len <= 0
 11        THEN
 12           retval := NULL;
 13        ELSIF LENGTH (par_tekst) < par_len
 14        THEN
 15           retval := par_tekst;
 16        ELSE
 17           l_str_1 := SUBSTR (par_tekst, 1, par_len);
 18           l_space_pos := INSTR (l_str_1, ' ', -1);
 19           retval := SUBSTR (l_str_1, 1, l_space_pos) || ' ...';
 20        END IF;
 21
 22        RETURN retval;
 23     END f_trim_text;
 24  /

Function created.
```

How does it work?

```
SQL> select deptno,
  2                listagg(ename, ', ' on overflow truncate)         as emps,
  3    substr     (listagg(ename, ', ' on overflow truncate), 1, 15) as substr_emps,
  4    f_trim_text(listagg(ename, ', ' on overflow truncate), 15   ) as trimmed_emps
  5  from emp
  6  group by deptno;

    DEPTNO EMPS                                               SUBSTR_EMPS          TRIMMED_EMPS
---------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
        30 ALLEN, WARD, MARTIN, BLAKE, TURNER, JAMES          ALLEN, WARD, MA      ALLEN, WARD,  ...
        10 CLARK, KING, MILLER                                CLARK, KING, MI      CLARK, KING,  ...
        20 SMITH, JONES, SCOTT, ADAMS, FORD                   SMITH, JONES, S      SMITH, JONES,  ...

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-calculate the cumulative length of the summaries using the `SUM` analytic function and then use conditional aggregation to aggregate the values until your limit is reached:

```sql
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE
         WHEN cumulative_length <= 10
         THEN summary
         END,
         ', '
       ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY priority) AS summaries
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         SUM(LENGTH(summary) + 2) OVER (
           PARTITION BY id ORDER BY priority, ROWNUM
         ) - 2 AS cumulative_length
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, summary, priority) AS
SELECT 'a', 'text',       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'goes',       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 'here',       3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'unaffected', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | SUMMARIES |
| --- | --- |
| a | text, goes |
| b | unaffected |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tIEmxiJ_)